# Would a background-image still load if it's hidden?

Tags: javascript, css

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578283/will-an-image-load-if-it-has-its-css-set-so-that-visibility-is-hidden) but I think it's for `<img>` tags. I'm not really sure if it's the same with `background-image`.

I'm making a responsive website and my issue is that I do not want images to load if it's accessed through mobile phones (or if it has a small window width). If the image is just applied with a `display: none;` if using `@media`, I think there would be wasted time and resources if the image is loaded anyway regardless if it's displayed on mobile phones.

What I need is for images (an `<img>` or an element with a `background-image`) to only load if it's visible. I'm kinda concerned of somehow optimizing the responsiveness of my site.

If it's done with javascript (or jQuery), it's nice if it's really lightweight. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently , opera is the only browser around which doesn't load a background-image for a hidden element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use media queries to remove the call to the background on smaller devices.

So if DIV X loads a BG on desktop you simply apply background-image: none to the same DIV for mobile rez in a min-max query. Do the same for desktop but in reverse so you load smaller or larger images.

So on a responsive site the mobile rez doesn't load an image at all since the .class has been told background-image: none. While the same .class has background-image:img.jpg for higher rez.

Comment: That is a great suggestion. I would now take this over the JS solution. Thanks! :)

Comment: This is not necessarily true. Some browsers will still download hidden background-images, depending on the markup structure http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/

Answer (score 5):

Quoting [this article](http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/11/do-hidden-elements-load-background-images/):

> images [backgrounds] for hidden elements, set via CSS or inline in the
>   element, would load every time, contrary to what we thought/expected.

BUT [unused css rules containing a background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396909/are-unused-css-images-downloaded) are not loaded.

So what you can do, is to dynamically add the background-image class, with javascript/jquery, only if the viewport is larger than X.

---

Here is a [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/9xVNR/) of how to do it.

HTML

```
<div id="yourdiv"></div>
```

CSS

```
#yourdiv {
    background:yellow;
}
#yourdiv.backgrounded {
  background:url(your-image.jpg) top left no-repeat;
}​
```

jQuery

```
$(window).on('load resize',function(){
    var w=window,
        d=document,
        e=d.documentElement,
        g=d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var docWidth = w.innerWidth||e.clientWidth||g.clientWidth;
    if(docWidth>600){ /* replace 600 with the screen width you want to target */
      yourdiv.addClass('backgrounded');
    }
});​
```

(jsFiddle doesn't trigger `load`, so you've to resize the doc to see it working)

---

**Warning**: This will probably cause a "delayed" loading of the image, so be sure to test the results.

Comment: As of now, the URL of the image is being retrieved from a database so it's being added inline. So how do I go about dynamically adding it?

Comment: @skii Sorry, i was writing down a demo. Well, can't you add a `<style>` on the doc's `head`, populated dynamically, instead of an inline style?

Comment: Yes, I could. I've already thought of how I would apply it in my Wordpress theme. Thank you so much, and I loled at the pic